# Is it possible to enable CLR stored procedures on SQL Server LocalDB

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, clr, localdb

The main problem is quite simple: I'm using a database from SQL Server which uses a CLR stored procedure, which I often use with the installed instance of SQL Server Express. Of course I don't have any problems of using those stored procedure in that database.

To be straight, the requirement I need is: to install a lightweight version of a database, because the application will run on different clients (like 15 machines), and I just need to install the local database by default. I cannot install the whole instance of SQL Server, because is too much time, and the customer does not want it that way.

So I found out that I can use a `.mdf` file to use a local database (and just install `SqlLocal.msi`), without the need of an Instance of SQL Server (actually I did a test by disabling the SQL services, and it worked).

The problem remains with the CLR stored procedures within the `.mdf` file. When I debugged my application, I realized that precisely in the part where I consume the CLR stored procedure it throws an exception, so I assume that it was a problem with the CLR.

How can I consume a CLR stored procedure using a local database within a `.mdf` file?

Comment: `.mdf` and LocalDB ***ARE*** SQL Server - just a very small, developer-oriented version of SQL Server that doesn't get installed as a Windows service, but will be launched when your app runs. Therefore, you enable the SQL-CLR in this database just like in any other SQL Server database (and there's ***tons*** of documentation on that - just **search**!)

Comment: Also, it's a **stored** procedure - as in a procedure that is **stored** inside your SQL Server database. It has nothing to do with a "store" .....